# Angular: Loading component from external module

Tags: angular

Im looking into if i should make my upcoming project in Angular or a different js-framework. I would like for the new project to be extendable by other developers (both frontend and backend). The backend shouldnt really be a problem, but im concerned that I wont be able load the frontend part of their extension and inject it into my views.

Is that a way to load components from an external module in Angular (from a js-filepath and a component-name) and how should my project-structure look in order for the developers to be able to use the services i create and create their own module that the main project can load and use the components of.

I know I can make it in AngularJS, but is it possible to do in Angular?

Answer (score 1):

This question has come up a number of times here, in different forms.

The basic answer is "no", you can't do that in Angular, at least not a runtime, for an AOT build.
You can load lazy modules, but they still have to be known at compile time.

You can (with a lot of work) do this for an non-AOT build, but I'm guessing that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: i would be fine with doing it with the JIT-compiler if that's an option (not knowing what the downside is with using the JIT compared to AOT)